# Create inverse react-router <Route /> path; hide on match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I would like a way to invert a Route by path, instead of include like the standard behavior.

Instead of doing:

```
<DefaultRoute path={['/home', '/contact']} component={NavbarButtons} /> <-- Keep adding for each new page
<DefaultRoute path={'/home'} component={Home} />
<DefaultRoute path={'/contact'} component={Contact} />
<DefaultRoute path={'/no-nav-page'} component={NoNavPage} />
```

I'd like to achieve this:

```
<DefaultRoute path={"*"} hidePath={['/no-nav-page']} component={NavbarButtons} />
<DefaultRoute path={'/home'} component={Home} />
<DefaultRoute path={'/contact'} component={Contact} />
<DefaultRoute path={'/no-nav-page'} component={NoNavPage} />
```

This becomes especially useful when you keep adding new pages, but want to include them in the default set of pages when the `NavbarButtons` show up, and not manually have to add a `path` definition for each new page.

I could use `useLocation` to match the path manually and conditionally render a component:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation()

return (
  <>
   {routeVars.hideTopbar.includes(pathname) ? null : <TopBar />}
  </>
)
```

But that becomes overcomplicated when using paths like `"/page/:id"`.

Answer (score 1):

The initial way of  specifying an inclusive set of routes you want the `NavbarButtons` component to render with is the standard conventional way of conditionally rendering routed content, but if you wanted to do the inverse you would need a route that unconditionally matched anything and then explicitly checked a set of routes to ***exclusively*** render content on.

The following example uses the [`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook to match a set of "hidepath" paths. If there is a match then the custom `InverseRoute` component returns `null` to "hide" the routed content, otherwise it returns a regular `Route` with the regular route props passed through. This pattern is just a specialized route protection implementation.

Example:

```
import { Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const InverseRoute = ({ hidePath, ...props }) => {
  const hide = useRouteMatch(hidePath);

  return hide ? null : <Route {...props} />;
};
```

```
<InverseRoute
  path="*"                    // <-- match anything
  hidePath={["/no-nav-page"]} // <-- hide on these matches
  component={NavbarButtons}
/>
<Switch>
  <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
  <Route path="/no-nav-page" component={NoNavPage} />
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit create-inverse-react-router-route-path-hide-on-match]